# binomial logistics regression with 4 Hypotheses. Do I add all variables once and I run the analysis? Or each time separately?

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, binary-data, normality-assumption

I have 1 binary dependent variable, 2 independent categorical variables and 1 ratio predictor which I centered. I have 4 H0s, testing first each IV separately on the DV (H1, H2), then both IVs on the DV(H3) and lastly I add the moderator(so I have 2 IVs and 1 Moderator = H4). Do I put all the hypotheses together? And how test the assumptions of binomial logistic regression in SPSS?

Comment: Do I also add all the control variables? do I have to center those as well?